# Finding escape velocity considering two gravitational fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, gravity, escape-velocity

A shuttle has to travel between earth and mars to a point $P$ where the gravitational force of each planet is equal. I need to calculate the energy required to reach the point $P$.

I was thinking of using the gravitational field of earth but I think I also need to consider the gravitational field of mars because close to $P$, mars' gravitational field is also helping the shuttle because of the force of attraction. I thought of subtracting the potential energy caused by mars' gravitational field but can't quite come up with an expression to do so.

Comment: The location P is going to be extremely dependent on where Earth and Mars are in their orbits,  and  regardless of where that location winds up, the gravity of the Sun is going to be the dominating gravitational factor.

Comment: First you have to reach escape velocity from earth, s , but then you have to go against the gravitational field of the sun, the forces of mars and earth are minor in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Earth and Mars system to be an isolated and stationary one since you haven't mentioned anything about other heavenly bodies or the orbits,

Obviously, we would have to apply conservation of energy here. And as you have already figured most of it out,
In the initial energy, we include:

1. the kinetic energy given to the shuttle
2. gravitational potential energy due to earth
3. gravitational potential energy due to mars

Similarly, we will include the following in the expression for final energy:

1. new gravitational potential energy due to earth
2. new gravitational potential energy due to mars

Here, our final energy is considered at the neutral point( where the fields of both planets cancel each other out )
This is because we are talking about escape velocity here which means the minimum velocity to be given so that the shuttle may escape the earth's field to reach Mars. And if we're able to send the shuttle just to the neutral point, then the shuttle would go towards Mars on its own as the field of Mars would dominate over that of Earth's

So you should first find the distance of the neutral point from either of the planets then simply find the distances of the neutral point from the planets and use them in the expression for potential energy.